# 'readFileDataStream' Error While uploading file to blazor webassembly running on azure

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I have deployed a blazor webassembly to Azure Web app service. When I upload the file shows  following errore:

Could not find 'readFileDataStream' ('readFileDataStream' was undefined). Error: Could not find 'readFileDataStream' ('readFileDataStream' was undefined).

```
 public async Task OnFileUpload(FileChangedEventArgs e)
{

        var file = e.Files.FirstOrDefault();
        byte[] bytes;
        if (file == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (file.Type != "text/csv")
        {
            AlertService.Error("Invalid File Format");
            TimelineToggle = "timeline-hide";
            return;
        }
        using (MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await file.OpenReadStream(long.MaxValue).CopyToAsync(result);
            bytes = result.ToArray();
            examSessions = new List<ExamSession>();
            var exceldata = CsvUtil.GetDataFromCSV<ExcelUpload>(bytes);
            if (exceldata == null)
            {
                TimelineToggle = "timeline-hide";
                return;
            }
            loading = true;
            model = await ExcelToModelService.UploadNewExam(exceldata.ToList());
            examSessions = model.ExamSessions;
            exam = model.Exam;
            TimelineToggle = "timeline-show";
            loading = false;
        }
}
```

I have tried uploading file on local project and same thing works without any issue.

Comment: For better answers, you should include the relevant code.